# PDF publishing in Tridion 2013sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing

Whether the default publishing format for PDF is file name + Tcm ID in 2013sp1. Whenever I try to publish page/component with pdf linked in it, it's getting published with Tcm ID at the end in file name. This is happening even if I use Default Finish Action tbb instead of dd4t tbbs.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: So, a few questions. Assuming you're using OOTB publishing and not Razor Mediator, DD4T etc.).

What exactly is *the question?* Is it just whether this is default, is it how to override - in which case, are you aware of the possible naming conflicts if you do choose to remove the addition of the TCMID - are the business happy with this (as you simply see a publish fail from the editor perspective and it's a _more technical_ approach to finding and fixing the root cause in the event of binary name conflicts.

Comment: In fact - here's a great link as to why this is so.. https://blog.indivirtual.nl/publishing-binary-assets-sdl-tridion/

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thank you for your response. yes I'm aware the blog you shared. I thought Tridion left the practice of using Tcm ID in file name but, dd4t reintroduced it. again I was surprised to see default (without dd4t) also Tcm ID is getting appended with file name for PDF. I just wanted to know is it specific only for 2013sp1 or for all other versions too.

Comment: tcmid is appended by default for all version, not just 2013sp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default system behavior when generating filenames of Multimedia items and is expected to be this way.

Below is the summary of what *Mark* and *Robert* have to say:

> **Mark:**
>
> So, a few questions. Assuming you're using OOTB publishing and not
>   Razor Mediator, DD4T etc.). What exactly is the question? Is it just
>   whether this is default, is it how to override - in which case, are
>   you aware of the possible naming conflicts if you do choose to remove
>   the addition of the TCMID - are the business happy with this (as you
>   simply see a publish fail from the editor perspective and it's a more
>   technical approach to finding and fixing the root cause in the event
>   of binary name conflicts.
>
> In fact - here's a great link as to why this is so..
>   https://blog.indivirtual.nl/publishing-binary-assets-sdl-tridion/
>
> **Robert:**
>
> tcmid is appended by default for all version, not just 2013sp1

Please mark the post as answered so that the question can be closed.